# javascript editing fields after manual edit of field

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, field

I've looked everywhere on this.

basically what I have is a script that changes the value of some fields based on a radio selection.

For example: Think of it like a radio button that gets credit card data.
it works initially when the page loads and selects a radio.  It will correctly load the data of that radio button.

Now when I choose to edit the fields manually, using it like a "new card" form, if I change my mind and go to select a presaved card, it will no longer update those fields I edited manually.  It will completely ignore my request for it to change values via my javascript code that was just previously working.  Note: It will actually still continue to work for any fields I left alone *did not manually type into/edit

so I was just wondering who else had that problem and what one does to fix it.

Comment: Can't help without showing some code. I think i understand what you are saying, but without looking at some code, it's hard to tell whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand exactly but I'll take a shot. My suggestion would be set apply a css class like "is-dirty" to the field once it has been updated and then you check to see if a given field has that class before updating it.